# Using INotifyPropertyChanged in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

Hi i am trying to use the NotifyPropertyChanged to update all the places where i am binding a property. For what i have searched the INotifyPropertyChanged is indicated to this cases.

So i need help because i don't understand what i have wrong in here. And i really don't know what to do with the PropertyChange event. My question about that is, when he changes? What i have to more with him?

Datagrid:

```
<ListView Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"/>
```

An example when i change my Categories property:

```
DataTest dtTest = new DataTest();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = dtTest;
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Here i pick up a string from a textBox, where i will insert in a Table of my DB,
    //Then i will do a query to my Table, and i will get a DataTable for example
    //Then i just put the contents into the DataView, so the value have changed.
    dtTest.Categories = dtTable.DefaultView;
    dtTest = dtTable.defaultView; (this only an example, i don't this for real.)
    //What i have to do now, to wherever i am binding (DataGrid, ListView, ComboBox)
    //the property to the new values automatically being showed in all places?
}
```

My Class:

```
public class DataTest : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataView categories;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; //What i have to do with this?

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string str)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(str));
        }
    }

    public DataView Categories
    {
        get { return categories; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != categories)
            {
                categorias = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Categories");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Class with INotifyCollectionChanged:

```
public class DataTest : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    public DataView Categories
    {
        get { return categories; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != categories)
            {
                categories = value;
                OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, Categories));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But why the PropertyChanged is always NULL??? I have to do something more, but i don't know what.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `DataTest` class needs to be the `DataContext` for the Binding. You can set this in code-behind (or a myriad of other ways, but for simplicity - just do it in code-behind)

```
public MainWindow() // constructor
{
    this.DataContext = new DataTest();
}
```

Then, with the 'Source' of the Binding set, you can specify the 'Path', so your xaml looks like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" />
```

Now, if the property 'Categories' is changed in code, the `NotifyPropertyChanged` code you have written will alert the Binding, which in turn will access the public getter for the property and refresh the view.

Comment: And i don't need to do anything with the event? Doesn't have to be initialized? Or he loses the Null value when the Properties started to be binded anywhere?

Comment: @Miguel Give it a try - the main thing is, set the DataContext for the thing you're binding, or preferably a parent, like the Window. And then, yes - Binding will do the work for you; you don't need to create a handler manually!

Comment: I tried what you suggested and how you have explained above, and i put a breakpoint in NotifyPropertyChanged to check if the PropertyChanged is null or not, but it stays null.

Comment: OK - couple of things. 1. Make sure the backing field is spelt correctly, you have it as 'categories' and 'categorias' in different places of your sample code (but maybe this is just a typo on this question?) and 2. Put the breakpoint on the property setter, because by the time that code is run (after you click the button), the Binding will be configured, and the PropertyChanged event will be non-null. It is possible you were breaking too soon, before the Binding was set up.

Comment: The event is always null. When i changed the values of the Property, the event just fired up, and is always always null. Are you sure that i don't have to intiliaze my PropertyChangedEventhandler?

Comment: @Miguel: Can you show your modified code? And yes, there is nothing to initialize in an event handler.

Comment: Absolutely. So next: Look in the debug output window. Go to Debug > Windows > Output. If the Binding is failing, there will be a line in there alerting you...

Comment: So i have done what you said, and when i have opened the Window in where i am trying to apply this, i got the following error: **System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Categories' property not found on 'object' ''DataTest' (HashCode=40007697)'. BindingExpression:Path=Categories; DataItem='DataTest' (HashCode=40007697); target element is 'ListView' (Name='listView'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')**.

Comment: Ok i have found the Problem, in my real case i have 'Categorias' and don't 'Categories' but anyway, when i change (like insert one value) the value he doesn't update my ListView... And the PropertyChanged stills Null...

Comment: @Miguel - *Just to test this* - Set the 'Categories' property type to be List<string>; then in the DataTest class constructor, create a new List<string>, put some dummy values in there, like "Red", "White" and "Blue" (anything will do) and set the property. Does the list of strings appear in your ListView?

Comment: With the DataView he already display the contents of my DataView in the ListView, but the PropertyChanged stills Null.

Comment: The 'dataTest' instance in the button-click handler - is it the same instance being set as the DataContext? It needs to be...

Comment: I have updated my question, with the part of where i set the Class as the DataContext...

Comment: @Miguel: If you want the ListView to update when you add/change items in your DataView then the DataView needs to implement INotifyCollectionChanged. Right now the ListView will only update when you actually replace the Categories with a complete different object. You probably want to have a look at this WPF binding tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: I have updated my question with the INotifyCollectionChanged. Can you check what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Getting the handler prevents the event handler from going to null after you check for null and checking for null will prevent you from getting a null exception if there are no event handlers.

The reason that your `PropertyChanged` is null is that there are no event handlers attached to it.  The reason there are not handlers attached to it is you have not bound your object to anything (which will take care of adding a handler) or you haven't added a handler to it (if you wanted to observe it for some other reason).  Once your object is created you need to bind it somewhere.

Comment: So in this cases what i have to do?

Comment: What do you want to happen in your control?  In most cases you don't create a binding after a button click but instead create the binding in the XAML.  If you have a ListBox and you want to bind the Categories to it you'd do <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Categories}/> assuming your DataContext is set to be DataTest object you want to populate the ItemsSource.  Most likely you need to have some way of exposing the current DataTest to the XAML (probably a DependencyProperty) and bind based upon that property.

Comment: I never have used Dependency Properties. I have a small idea of what they are but i have never used. I have exposed my real situation below in a comment of other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all you have to do.  An event is just a special kind of delegate.  You declare it, you invoke it, clients subscribe to it.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Ok so my case is the following... I Update that DataView, i do a query for example and put Data into the DataView, and the value of the Property have changed, but the PorpertyChanged event is always null!! Why? I have to do something more with PropertyChanged but i can't understand what and where... That is my problem. Imagine that i have clicked in a button and then i have changed the value of that property, what i have to do next?

Comment: If `PropertyChanged` is null that means there are no clients listening to the event.  Why that would be is hard to say without more information.

Comment: Have that anything to do with the Bindings? I am binding the property in more than one place, so i don't think that it have to do with the bindings. I have to do something more but can't figure it out what... Have i to do something like this "dtTest.PropertyChanged = ?" ???

Comment: Edit your question with a small example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I have edited my Button_Click event, to give a better explaination. So i think that i have to attach some handler to my PropertyChanged or do something with it in my Window so he isn't NULL, right? But what?

Comment: What you seem to be missing is that the PropertyChanged is there for exactly one purpose: to support data binding.  In your example above, you are not showing any databinding code.

Comment: I just read over your comments again--I think you need to read up on databinding, how it is used, etc.  Binding data to XAML is what the PropertyChanged event is for.  If you are setting the Categories property in your code behind, you are NOT doing databinding.

Comment: So how can i do to my Properties whenever are changed, update the places where are being binded to show the new values?

Comment: @Miguel: Also once you get notifications working, `static` is going to cause you some trouble.

Comment: I have edited my question with an example of how i am doing in a ListView for example...

Comment: Sorry. With a Static it was i am just doing before, binding a Static Resource. But i need to update all the places when i add new values to a collection for example. But i can't understand how this works.

Comment: @Miguel: It appears you have multiple `dtTest` objects and you are getting them confused.  You need to update the same one that the binding refers to.

Comment: OK so i ask which is the best approach to my problem? After i am trying the implementation of INotifyPropertyChange, i was working only with Static Properties, but they were accessible anywhere. But now what i should do?

Comment: @Miguel: Databinding and INotifyPropertyChanged work great, everybody uses them.  You just have to learn how to use them but these things take time.  We can help if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Ok i can post some more code to explain better. But what i am doing is, i have a Main Window where i have a DataGrid that will show a Table. So some of the columns in the DataGrid are DataGridComboBoxColumn and the DataViews populate them. So there is one place where use them. And then i have other Window to manage Categories, Places, Suppliers and etc. And in these Windows i have ListViews which i populate them with the DataViews to. So i am looking for the better way to when i add more Categories to the DataView, and after i have done a query to update it, i refresh the values in everywhere.