# Binding bool to visibility in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to change the visibility of the TextBlock with a Binding depending on the state of the boolean variable of the code behind

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

This don't work :(

```
    private bool _isVisible = false;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return _isVisible; }
        set
        {
            _isVisible = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: Have you worked with [`inotifypropertyhanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1) before? if not then I invite you to read about it.

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain it to me with code?

Comment: [Simple small INotifyPropertyChanged implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3851144/5228202) https://stackoverflow.com/q/5785265/5228202 you will find plenty of example if you make a little search.

Comment: your variable name is wrong here: `public bool isVisible`, should be `IsVisible`

Comment: @Cfun is right. This is one of the reasons you should use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) and/or [`CallerMemberName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute).

Comment: I edited the post, don't work with CallerMemberName

Comment: @user10438104 have you solve this issue? I'm facing the same issue as you, can you share how you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is within your propertyname `IsVisible`. You are in the CodeBehind of a `Window` or a `UserControl`, so there is already a property called `IsVisible` which comes from the `Window`/`UserControl`.

Just change the name of your property to something like `IsCurrentlyVisible` and your code will work.

If you have more places in your code where you have to set the `Visibility` of a control dependent on a bool-property I would recommend you to use a converter instead of the style.

The converter-class for converting a bool-value to a `Visibility` looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Playground
{
    internal class BoolToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        private static BoolToVisibilityConverter converter;

        // ReSharper disable once EmptyConstructor
        public BoolToVisibilityConverter()
        {

        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return converter ?? (converter = new BoolToVisibilityConverter());
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool b && b)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage of this converter is just as easy as:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello" Visibility="{Binding IsCurrentlyVisible, Converter={local:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: How is this different from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?

Comment: It differs, because my converter is derived from `MarkupExtension`. So I don't need to create a resource for it. I can use it directly where I need it.